# Array error due to size assignment

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am doing and example for C programming class:

```
#define xSize 2
#define ySize 3

int x,y, a[xSize][ySize];
for (x=1; x<=xSize; x++){

for (y=1; y<=ySize; y++){
a[x][y]=(x*x)+(y*y);}}

for (x=1; x<=xSize; x++){

for (y=1; y<=ySize; y++){
printf("a[%d][%d]= %d   ", x, y, a[x][y]);}}
```

It gives an Error when I try to compile in "Xcode-macOS"

But when i give **int x,y, a[xSize+1][ySize+1]** it compiles fine, why it happens ?

Comment: Array indexes start at `0` and go to `size-1`, not from `1` to `size`.

Comment: Go back to your textbook and reread the chapter on arrays.

Comment: Thank you, I will read again

Comment: .. and check out about indenting the code to make it readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `a[xSize]` and `b[ySize]`. The array `a` can store up to `xSize` values while `b` can store up to `ySize` values. However that starts from index 0 to `xSize-1` and 0 to `ySize-1` in arrays `a` and `b` respectively. So when you are using for loop you are iterating the loop with indexes from 1 to `xSize` when actually the array is limited to a maximum index of `xSize-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Array indexing starts from 0. In your for loop you iterate with x=1 && x<=size. The conditions should be x = 0 && x < size. Same applies for all dimensions of the array.

Comment: But the example that i am doing specifically starts with 1 not 0

Comment: @ZulfidinKhodzhaev: Then your example is not coded for native C — nor for a language derived from C (such as C++, Java, JavaScript, Go, C#, …).  If you want to code an algorithm with 1-based arrays, you will have to allocate more space — the `+1` — to get the algorithm to work semi-sanely.  You may still have problems.  It would better to rework the algorithm to use 0-based arrays.  And the idiomatic C loops for iterating over the elements of an array use the notation `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)` — use them and only deviate when crucial and you know what you're doing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler . Thank you very much. I understand now.